# R user-defined functions in new environment

Tags: r

I use some user-defined small functions as helpers. These functions are all stored in a `R_HOME_USER/helper`directory. Until now, these functions were sourced at R start up. The overall method is something like `lapply(my.helper.list,source). I want now these functions to be sourced **but not to appear in my environment**, as they pollute it.

A first and clean approach would be to build a package with all my helper.R. For now, I do not want to follow this method. A second approach would be to name these helpers with a leading dot. This annoys me to have to run `R > .helper1()`.

Best way would be to define these helpers in a specific and accessible environment, but I am messing with the code. My idea is to create first a new environment:

```
.helperEnv <- new.env(parent = baseenv())
attach(.helperEnv, name = '.helperEnv')
```

Fine, `R > search()` returns **'helperEnv'** in the list. Then I run :

```
assign('helper1', helper1, envir = .helperEnv)
rm(helper1)
```

Fine, `ls(.helperEnv)`returns **'helper1'** and this function does not appear anymore in my environment.
The issue is I can't run helper1 (object not found). I guess I am not on the right track and would appreciate some hints.

Comment: If you're going to go through the trouble of trying to set up a separate environment, why not just do the package? Lots of folks have personal R packages with these types of helper functions.

Comment: @hrbrmstr doing the package is the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should assign the `pos` argument in your call to `attach` as a negative number:

```
    .helperEnv <- new.env()
    .helperEnv$myfunc<-function(x) x^3+1
    attach(.helperEnv,name="helper",pos=-1)
    ls()
    #character(0)
    myfunc
    #function(x) x^3+1
```